# MySQL merge two records into one

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have status table with

```
id (primary key )
case id 
read status
delivered status
```

now I can have multiple records for same case id with different values

Here I have **case ID (111)** with two rows

```
ID  case_id     read_status     delivered_status
1   111         1                0
2   111         0                1
```

How can I run query so it gives one row for above case with read status and delivery status to 1 ?

**SqlFiddle**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d977e/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> read status and delivery status to 1

Do you mean the max value ? If so, here is the fiddle.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d977e/3)

The query :

```
select 
  `case_id`,
  max(`read_status`),
  max(`delivered_status`)
from status
group by `case_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

you can group by case_id, and simply get max value of the colum in group

```
select id, case_id ,max(read_status) as read_status , max(delivered_status) as delivered_status  from status group by case_id
```